# Operating VirtualBox 5 on old Pentium 4 32bit CPU with 4GB RAM

Tags: virtualization, virtual-memory

Trying to operate VirtualBox 5 on old Pentium 4 32bit CPU with 4GB RAM. But spinning up 32bit Linux/Ubuntu VMs is so slow. Have adjusted allocation of RAM and hard drive settings and still too slow.

Please, can anyone offer any insights to settings, adjustments or other strategies to speed up VM creation given these parameters?

Comment: This question does not seem to be security related. You might consider migrating this question to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Too slow in what aspect? CPU speed? IO? Network? What is your host OS, and how much RAM have you allocated to the virtual machine? This is a 15 year-old processor you are talking about, why would you expect it to be fast?

Comment: @BadSkillz: thanks for replying. Advice well taken. To explain, I am working on building a simple hardware "lab" on an older unused machine to test black hat intrusion and device intelligence defeating or masking or spoofing. Since I had been asking other security related questions, did not think to take it elsewhere on StackExchange. You are right. On the other hand, my experience since posting the above and the comments below, think I will just leave it here as it is resolved.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: no presumption on my part that it ought to be fast. Just trying to stretch the utility of available hardware for a specific task. In any event, thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CPU doesn't support [VT-x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29) then virtualization will be much slower. You can check in /proc/cpuinfo for the vmx flag. It is possible the flag is disabled in the BIOS so you should check there if you don't have the flag.

Other than that, I think my advice would be to get a faster newer machine to run VMs on.

Comment: Thanks, Douglas. On your advice to check for VT-x found this neat little tool from [Microsoft® Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592) which, in short, after running it told me to take your advice. Should anyone else have the same question, the above tool took me maybe 5 to download, execute and learn unequivocally that I was wasting my time at least with respect to VirtualBox. VMware Player actually virtualized.